# Loop through nav menu as if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav menu set to days of the week, when the webpage is opened / and or if the user hasn't performed an action for a certain amount of time, I would like the page to cycle through the days of the week as if they were clicked with a delay of 15 seconds or so in between.

```
<div id="nav" class="inner dark-blue">
   <ul>
      <li id="sunday" style='border: none'>Sunday</li>
      <li id="monday">Monday</li>
      <li id="tuesday">Tuesday</li>
      <li id="wednesday">Wednesday</li>
      <li id="thursday">Thursday</li>
      <li id="friday">Friday</li>
      <li id="saturday">Saturday</li>
      <li id="about">About</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What's the best way to do this with JavaScript? I've tried setTimeout but it doesn't work as expected.

Edit:

I am part of the way there now with the below code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuitems.length; i++){
  $(menuitems[i]).delay(10000*i).queue(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click'); /**Nearly there!**/
  });
};
```

This goes from Sunday to Saturday and stops, I'd like it to return back to Sunday.

Comment: Each menu item contains different pages to be loaded, or its content will be displayed in tabs?

Comment: I have a div that has a certain iframe appended depending on which is clicked.

Comment: i think you have to use `setInterval() and setTimeout()` both to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.setInterval(function,milliseconds,lang);
```

[Reference link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)